# Error or not and insert to database mysql

Tags: php

Why wont this work?

```
<?php include "top.php"; 
include "connect.php";
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$error = "";
    if(empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error .= "Du glömde märket!<br>";
        if(empty($_POST["rating"])){
        $error .= "Du glömde att bedömma märket!<br>";
                if(empty($_POST["worth"])){
        $error .= "Du glömde att välja vilken klass den hör till!<br>";
                if(empty($_POST["username"])){
        $error .= "Du glömde att skriva ditt namn!<br>";
                if(empty($_POST["rating"])){
        $error .= "Du glömde att skriva någonting?!!<br>";
        }}}}}
    if(!empty($error)){
    echo $error;
    }else{
$name = $_POST["name"];
$rating = $_POST["rating"];
$worth = $_POST["worth"];
$favorite = $_POST["favorite"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$description = $_POST["description"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO brands (name, rating, worth, favorite, username, description) VALUES ('$name', '$rating', '$worth', '$favorite', '$username', '$description')");
echo "<span style='color: green'>Yir yir, <a href='brand.php'>klicka här för att gå till Märken.</a></span>";
    }
    }
```

It doesnt come with errors it just say the succeed message like it has inserted to database

Comment: I've no idea. Why have I no idea? It's hard to answer questions without being told what the problem is. What happens when you run that code? Do you get an error? Does your computer melt in front of your eyes?

Comment: I wonder if anyone has put together stats on "PHP questions involving SQL" compared with "PHP questions with SQL Injection Vulnerabilities"…? @Azzyh — you need to read http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.We can't help you unless you at least try to get some debug information.

For instance, replace

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO brands (name, rating, worth, favorite, username, description) VALUES ('$name', '$rating', '$worth', '$favorite', '$username', '$description')");`

With

```
$query = "INSERT INTO brands (name, rating, worth, favorite, username, description) VALUES ('$name', '$rating', '$worth', '$favorite', '$username', '$description')";

echo "Query: " . $query;

mysql_query($query);
```

It echoes the query to the screen before executing it, perhaps it provides some more information.

Answer (score 0):

echo the query u have created and see what is displayed and execute that query for testing in phpmyadmin